# What is the maximum number of validators in current PoC of Eth2.0?

Tags: casper

In the current spec no maximum number of validators is mentioned: https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/master/specs/beacon-chain.md
but is there some implicit upper bound for the number of validators?